# mapper [NpgsqlValue] cannot be changed from type [date] to [ObjectMapper]

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I am trying to import exception from my log file generated by Serilog into ElasticSearch and I am getting 400 with this error message:

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "mapper [fields.ExceptionDetail.Statement.InputParameters.Collection.NpgsqlValue] cannot be changed from type [date] to [ObjectMapper]"
```

Here is json for the exception:

```
{
   "@timestamp":"2021-10-23T18:07:01.3922829+03:00",
   "level":"Error",
   "messageTemplate":"Duplicate value",
   "message":"Duplicate value",
   "exceptions":[
      {
         "Depth":0,
         "ClassName":"Npgsql.PostgresException",
         "Message":"23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"Table1_pkey\"",
         "Source":"Npgsql",
         "StackTraceString":"   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at Dapper.Logging.Hooks.WrappedCommand`1.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader)\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)\r\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)\r\n   at Dapper.FastCrud.SqlStatements.GenericSqlStatements`1.InsertAsync(IDbConnection connection, TEntity entity, AggregatedSqlStatementOptions`1 statementOptions) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Dapper.FastCrud\\SqlStatements\\GenericSqlStatements.cs:line 112\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.Domain.Database.DbRepository.InsertTable1() in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.Domain\\Database\\DbRepository.cs:line 64\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.Domain.Services.MainService.Action(ActionRequest request, DateTime receivedTimestamp) in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.Domain\\Services\\MainService.cs:line 36\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.customer.customerService.Action(ActionRequest request, DateTime receivedTimestamp) in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.customer\\customerService.cs:line 34\r\n   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.Infrastructure.Middleware.LoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.Infrastructure\\Middleware\\LoggingMiddleware.cs:line 25\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.Infrastructure.Middleware.CorrelationIdMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.Infrastructure\\Middleware\\CorrelationIdMiddleware.cs:line 61\r\n   at SecurityIntegration.Infrastructure.Middleware.ErrorHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\\Projects\\security-integration\\security-integration-git\\securityIntegration.Infrastructure\\Middleware\\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 35",
         "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
         "RemoteStackIndex":0,
         "HResult":-2147467259,
         "HelpURL":null
      }
   ],
   "fields":{
      "SourceContext":"SecurityIntegration.Infrastructure.Middleware.ErrorHandlerMiddleware",
      "RequestId":"0HMCM6R1JP88C:00000002",
      "RequestPath":"/v1/security/customer/Action",
      "ConnectionId":"0HMCM6R1JP88C",
      "ExceptionDetail":{
         "Data":{
            "Severity":"ERROR",
            "InvariantSeverity":"ERROR",
            "SqlState":"23505",
            "MessageText":"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"Table1_pkey\"",
            "Detail":"Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.",
            "SchemaName":"public",
            "TableName":"Table1",
            "ConstraintName":"Table1_pkey",
            "File":"d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\access\\nbtree\\nbtinsert.c",
            "Line":"570",
            "Routine":"_bt_check_unique"
         },
         "HResult":-2147467259,
         "Message":"23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"Table1_pkey\"",
         "Source":"Npgsql",
         "IsTransient":false,
         "Statement":{
            "SQL":"INSERT INTO \"Table1\" (\"Parameter1\",\"Parameter2\",\"Parameter3\") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) ",
            "StatementType":"Unknown",
            "Rows":0,
            "LongRows":0,
            "OID":0,
            "InputParameters":[
               {
                  "ConvertedValue":null,
                  "ParameterName":"Parameter1",
                  "Value":"79cdec6e-0c7b-49d7-b0dd-1c5755b833b1",
                  "NpgsqlValue":"79cdec6e-0c7b-49d7-b0dd-1c5755b833b1",
                  "DbType":"String",
                  "NpgsqlDbType":"Text",
                  "DataTypeName":"threw System.NotImplementedException: Infer from others",
                  "IsNullable":false,
                  "Direction":"Input",
                  "Precision":0,
                  "Scale":0,
                  "Size":4000,
                  "SourceColumn":"",
                  "SourceVersion":"Current",
                  "SourceColumnNullMapping":false,
                  "$id":"1",
                  "Collection":[
                     {
                        "$ref":"1"
                     },
                     {
                        "ConvertedValue":null,
                        "ParameterName":"Parameter2",
                        "Value":{
                           "_typeTag":"DBNull"
                        },
                        "NpgsqlValue":{
                           "_typeTag":"DBNull"
                        },
                        "DbType":"String",
                        "NpgsqlDbType":"Text",
                        "DataTypeName":"threw System.NotImplementedException: Infer from others",
                        "IsNullable":false,
                        "Direction":"Input",
                        "Precision":0,
                        "Scale":0,
                        "Size":0,
                        "SourceColumn":"",
                        "SourceVersion":"Current",
                        "SourceColumnNullMapping":false,
                        "Collection":{
                           "$ref":"Cyclic reference"
                        },
                        "PostgresType":null,
                        "$id":"2"
                     },
                     {
                        "ConvertedValue":null,
                        "ParameterName":"Parameter3",
                        "Value":"2021-10-23T18:07:00.7187309+03:00",
                        "NpgsqlValue":"2021-10-23T18:07:00.7187309+03:00",
                        "DbType":"DateTime",
                        "NpgsqlDbType":"Timestamp",
                        "DataTypeName":"threw System.NotImplementedException: Infer from others",
                        "IsNullable":false,
                        "Direction":"Input",
                        "Precision":0,
                        "Scale":0,
                        "Size":0,
                        "SourceColumn":"",
                        "SourceVersion":"Current",
                        "SourceColumnNullMapping":false,
                        "Collection":{
                           "$ref":"Cyclic reference"
                        },
                        "PostgresType":null,
                        "$id":"3"
                     }
                  ],
                  "PostgresType":null
               },
               {
                  "$ref":"2"
               },
               {
                  "$ref":"3"
               }
            ]
         },
         "Severity":"ERROR",
         "InvariantSeverity":"ERROR",
         "SqlState":"23505",
         "Code":"23505",
         "MessageText":"duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"Table1_pkey\"",
         "Detail":"Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.",
         "Hint":null,
         "Position":0,
         "InternalPosition":0,
         "InternalQuery":null,
         "Where":null,
         "SchemaName":"public",
         "TableName":"Table1",
         "ColumnName":null,
         "DataTypeName":null,
         "ConstraintName":"Table1_pkey",
         "File":"d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\access\\nbtree\\nbtinsert.c",
         "Line":"570",
         "Routine":"_bt_check_unique",
         "ErrorCode":-2147467259,
         "Type":"Npgsql.PostgresException"
      },
      "MachineName":"MACHINE-NAME"
   }
}
```

I believe it is because NpgsqlValue has all this different values (text/ObjectMapper/date):

```
"NpgsqlValue":"79cdec6e-0c7b-49d7-b0dd-1c5755b833b1"
"NpgsqlValue":{"_typeTag":"DBNull"}
"NpgsqlValue":"2021-10-23T08:31:54.5474090Z"
```

Could you please give me advice how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [mapper [NpgsqlValue] cannot be changed from type [date] to [ObjectMapper]](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/issues/420) to solve the described problem I have 2 options:

1. Remove Exception's details from my log by deleting "WithExceptionDetails" from config file and wait for Postgres exceptions' destructurer to appear.
2. Write custom destructurer.